# Safari print issue with javascript window.print()

Tags: javascript, printing, safari

I am having an issue with print on Safari. My System is Windows 7, and this function works fine in all other browsers except Safari. Here is the situation:

```
window.onload = function(){
    console.log('before print');
    window.print();
}
```

It won't output the log in console panel, but the print page will appear first, after i choose cancel in print page, the log will be output.

Does any body came up with this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

**Updated**

Here is the situation i have:
We need to print a page whose content can be changed by user by checking and unchecking check box, and only the content part of this page should be printed, so we create a new page that only contains the content for printing. In this page, we need to hide the unnecessary content that is not selected by user, so we need to do some DOM operation before `window.print()` get called. The `console.log()` is just an example code for observing. I tried to add an `<div id='test'>Test HTML</div>` in test HTML and add

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.style.background = 'yellow';
```

before `window.print();`, it shows the same result in my Safari browser, the 'Test HTML' will not turn to yellow until i click cancel button in print panel, so it's not just the `console.log` issue.

**Updated**

I am using Safari 5.1.7(7534.57.2) on Windows 7

Comment: Just a note (I know it's a late comment, but it's applicable back to '14). Safari was discontinued for Windows back in '12 (when Safari 6 came out). So if you're trying to test Safari on Windows, know that it won't be representative of Safari on Mac, and know that many "new" features (like some HTML5 things) just plain won't work, or won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several times trying, below code works, but i don't know the reason, can anybody explain? Or this is a Safari Bug?

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('body').html('After change');
    setTimeout(window.print, 1000);
};
```

Comment: The issue is that browsers halt javascript execution when print is initialized. Safari may be initializing the print before the console.log executes, meaning it delays the log.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the `setTimeout` solution didn't work. I found this jQuery plugin https://github.com/jasonday/printThis that has plenty of workarounds for `window.print()` because it seems not to be fully supported by all browsers.

I took this line that worked for me Safari `document.execCommand("print", false, null)`

and this worked ok for me for now in safari and chrome

```
try {
  document.execCommand('print', false, null);
}
catch(e) {
  window.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is odd behavior. I tested in Safari 6.1 on Mac.

But may I ask why you need to log something before the printing? Because it seems that all the functions are being executed before the printing panel pops up:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {

    $('body').html('before print');

    console.log('before print');

    window.print();
};
</script>
```

When you look at the print preview, the page will have the text "before print" on it. For some reason, the console will log the text only when the print panel closes, but in my opinion that doesn't really matter for your visitors. You can manipulate DOM and change the page before the printing process as you like.

Comment: Yes @Stephan, there is no necessary to add `console.log`, but i really need add DOM manipulation code before `window.print()`, and on my Safari, the `window.print();` always execute before JS code prior to it, the same thing happens even if i replace `window.print()` instead of  `setTimeout(window.print(),5000)`.

Comment: Well, thats my whole point, the DOM gets manipulated before `window.print()`. Try my example in safari, when you look at the print preview, you will see that there is text on the page

Comment: No, in my real code, i do manipulates DOM before `window.print()`, and it doesn't work, that's why i am asking this question. You can see my updates on the question, i tried to change an element's text color before `window.print();`, but the color didn't change before i click the cancel button on print panel.

Comment: I just did another test where I changed the text color and background-color and it did work fine. It does not show on the page until you cancel the print dialog, but when I printed the page it did have the changed color, even without setTimeout, so I'm not sure why it won't work with your code

Comment: Well, maybe it's just an issue happens on Windows Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Safari prints the page before it is loaded unlike other browsers. Hence window.onload() can be used in the code of the newly opened html page. But if the page opened is non html content, then it is not possible. The below solution is global across browsers and type of content open.

```
var printWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
$(printWindow).load(function()
{
    this.print();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more solution which worked for my case:

First make your popup window.

```
$( ".myButton" ).click(function() {
    var url = 'www.google.com';
    var printWindow = window.open( url, '_blank');  
    printWindow.focus();
});
```

Then, inside the HTML page which is loaded in the popup:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

    setTimeout( function () { 

      try {
        document.execCommand('print', false, null);
      }
      catch(e) {
        window.print();
      }

    }, 500);

});
```