# window.print(); does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

The print method does not work on window when using an onclick link Safari. What is the alternative to have a webpage print, in safari via onclick code that is placed on a button? Another odd behavior that's occurring is that when I try and close the window, the print dialog native to the browser then appears.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626998/safari-print-issue-with-javascript-window-print

Comment: Its not the print method, its the on click function that does not work in safari

Comment: that solution no longer works

Comment: @ODelibalta really, jeez. k i'll remove and give it a shot

Comment: Put a console log in the onclick function instead so you can see whether the function is firing at all or not.

Comment: Works for me in Safari on Windows.

Comment: @ODelibalta yeah it's firing on all browsers except Safari

Comment: I took out the onclick attribute and put it in `ng-click="printOut()"` it still doesn't work

Comment: a button or a link? (you mention both)

Comment: Hey, man. Have you solved this problem? I'm facing the same behavior right now.

Comment: Nope, sorry I haven't

Comment: Not sure what OS is being used. Safari was discontinued for Windows with Safari 6 (2012).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
try {
  // Print for Safari browser
  document.execCommand('print', false, null)
} catch {
  window.print()
}
```

Comment: This try catch statement did not run for me but the `document.execCommand` does work in Safari. I rewrote this to check for the browser and conditionally run each statement.

Comment: This will silently fail for Firefox 94 without throwing any error.

Comment: [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is deprecated as of today.

Comment: (2022 July 26): Does not work. 50% opens op the small white print window which then results in an empty document

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue with the Safari browser (and not any others).
In my case, aborting all API calls currently in progress immidiately showed the native print dialog.

I'm guessing the reason why your dialog showed up when trying to close the tab/page is that all the network requests are cancelled then.

Here's an example of how to create a pool of ajax requests (when using jQuery):
[Stop all active ajax requests in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery#8841412)

Also, to make it work consistently, I had to wrap the `$.xhrPool.abortAll` function in a short timeout (100ms).

My click handler function (simplified) looks something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $.xhrPool.abortAll()
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you return the result of `window.print()` to the onclick handler, Safari will not display the print window.  I use React and had to make the following change:

```
//code that does not work:
<button type="button" onClick={() => window.print()}>Print!</button>

//code that does work:
<button type="button" onClick={() => { window.print(); }}>Print!</button>
```

All other browsers I tested (except Safari on iOS) worked fine either way, such as Chrome on iOS or Chrome for desktop.

My best guess is that as `window.print` is known to be asynchronous in Safari, perhaps `window.print()` returns falsy to the onclick handler, which cancels any "popups" from being displayed.  This may be why the sample above with the `myFunction()` code may work when having `onclick="window.print()"` may not work.

Answer (score 1):

This currently works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari:

```
try {
  if(!document.execCommand('print', false, null)) {
    window.print()
  }
} catch {
  window.print()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame3";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var mywindow = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.documentElement ? frame1.contentDocument.documentElement : frame1.contentDocument;
            mywindow.document.open();
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + strTitle + '</title>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame3"].focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                window.frames["frame3"].print(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function () {
               document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 20000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Have no problem with `window.print()` with **Safari**. Sorry I could not try on Windows OS but follow code works for me with MacOS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click link</a>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      window.print();
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```